# Cannot login with facebook test user

Tags: facebook, testing

I created two Facebook test user accounts using the Developer-Website->Apps->Roles->Test Users

i changes names and passwords.

when i try to login i get this error message:

> Incorrect Email The email you entered does not belong to any account.
>
> You can login using any email, username or mobile phone number
>   associated with your account. Make sure that it is typed correctly.

when i use the account switch option it works. problem is i need to test with android apps and cannot login :(

Comment: I'm getting the same thing using the facebook test user api